# Text getting out of figsize plot.bar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to fix the str numbers getting out of my plot.bar() without change the figsize. This is possible ?

My code:

```
ax = dados["NU_IDADE"].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar(figsize=(25, 10))

for p in ax.patches:
  percent_label_text = (p.get_height() / len(dados)) * 100
  ax.annotate(f'{str(round(percent_label_text, 2 if percent_label_text >= 0.01 else 3))}%', (p.get_x(), p.get_height()), rotation='vertical', xytext=(2, 5), textcoords="offset points")
```

My plot.bar:

[image: my ploy bar]

Comment: Manually set y-axis limit with `ax.set_ylim(0, 25000)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`ax.set_ylim(..)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html)  just after `plot.bar` command, which will help you to customise  the minimum and maximum limits of the y-axis. For example,:

```
ax = dados["NU_IDADE"].value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar(figsize=(25, 10))
ax.set_ylim([0,22500])

for p in ax.patches:
  percent_label_text = (p.get_height() / len(dados)) * 100
  ax.annotate(f'{str(round(percent_label_text, 2 if percent_label_text >= 0.01 else 3))}%', (p.get_x(), p.get_height()), rotation='vertical', xytext=(2, 5), textcoords="offset points")
```

Comment: Worked very well. Thanks! I just made some changes in the values